# Only apply css styles to one image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on a simple project where I have this back button which is called for via this line:

```
<a href="index.html" class="_container">
<img class="image backArrow" src="arrowBackWhite.png">
</a>
```

Then the CSS for it:

```
.backArrow {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  widt: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, my problem is that I have some css for all the other images to resize / work responsively which is this code:

```
/* Images */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

My question is, would it be possibly for the backArrow to not be affected by the imgs CSS?

Comment: yes, this is possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the CSS `:not` selector:

```
img:not(.backArrow){
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

[MDN Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
img.backArrow {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Target the img attribute & class.

Answer (score 0):

CSS takes the last styles applied to an element so I suggest to always put the most specific styles below the general ones.

So you could have first:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

and after:

```
.backArrow {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So CSS takes the .backArrow styles and overrides any previous styles done to the elements with that class.
https://jsfiddle.net/m872jj8u/

Answer (score 0):

**For general:**

```
/* Images */

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**The unique image css look like:**

```
.backArrow {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  widt: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**using the not property of css:**

```
img:not(.backArrow) {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

this is the new general css for your image, this is apply only to the images that has't the class named `backArrow`.